# Symmetric alpha-stable random vector with uniform spectral measure

Tags: integration, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

### Task

I am trying to solve Exercise 2.19 from [1]:

> Suppose $(X_1, X_2)$ is a S$\alpha$S vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with
> uniform spectral measure $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma(S_2) = 1$. Use
> polar coordinates to evaluate the joint characteristic function of
> $(X_1, X_2)$.

### My attempt

The characteristic function of $(X_1, X_2)$ should be given by
$$
\varphi(s_1, s_2) = \exp\bigg\{ 
- \int_{S_2} \vert s_1t_1 + s_2t_2 \vert^\alpha \,\,\Gamma(dt)
\bigg\}, \quad s_1, s_2 \in \mathbb{R}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the unique, finite, symmetric spectral measure $\Gamma$ on the unit circle $S_2$.
Consequently, using polar coordinates to transform the exponent gives us
$$
\int_{S_2} \vert s_1t_1 + s_2t_2 \vert^\alpha \,\,\Gamma(dt)
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \vert s_1\cos(\psi) + s_2\sin(\psi) \vert^\alpha \,\,d\psi.
$$
However, now I am at a loss of how to evaluate this integral. From [Wikipedia's entry on isotropic multivariate stable vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_stable_distribution#Isotropic_multivariate_stable_distribution), I know that the result should go along the lines of
$$
\varphi(s_1, s_2) =  \exp \{ 
-\gamma_0^\alpha \vert s_1^2 + s_2^2 \vert^{\alpha / 2}
\},
$$
where $\gamma_0$ is some positive constant.
Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+abs%28s_1cos%28x%29+%2B+s_2sin%28x%29%29%5E2+from+x+%3D+0+to+2pi)  shows me that my substitution gives the correct result at least for $\alpha = 2$ (possibly modulo normalization). So, I think the substitution is not wrong but nevertheless I do not know how to compute further steps.

### Literature

[1] Samorodnitsky, G., & Taqqu, M.S. (1994). Stable Non-Gaussian Random Processes: Stochastic Models with Infinite Variance: Stochastic Modeling (1st ed.). Routledge. https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203738818